# How do I insert multiple spans into an HTML element at specified indices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby, highlight

Background:

I’m implementing a feature that allows users to capture and persist their highlights using JavaScript/jQuery/HTML/CSS for frontend and Ruby/Rails for backend. I’ve already created a feature to persist highlights in the database, which are nested in an array (i.e. `[[<start_highlight_index >,<end_highlight_index >],…]`). But, I still need to implement a feature to load existing highlights on page load.

Simplified Example:

Given a paragraph element `<p>Hello world</p>` and an array of `[[1,4],[6,10]]`, what is the best way to create the following element:

```
<p><span style="background-color:yellow">Hello</span> <span style="background-color:yellow">world</span></p>
```

Note that spans were inserted to highlight “Hello” and “world”.  Although there are multiple ways to implement this, it’d be great to hear your suggestions for efficient ways to do this, since I want to keep the page load times to a minimum.

Comment: Writing code would be a good start. That's your job. We're here to (maybe) help fix what you do end up writing.

Comment: The code attempts that you've written I do not see

Comment: I’m the author of this post: It actually isn’t my job - yet. I’m new to programming and this is a project I’m building for fun. I don’t know why asking a question related to design and algorithms is inappropriate on this site?

Comment: Because (a) this site has guidelines (b) lots of people who use this site do this for a living and learned and earned answers to programming questions by lots of trial, error, and frustration first

Comment: Did you tried rangy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's javascript code which works for your purpose

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var content = $("p").html();
  var arr = [[1,4],[6,10]];
  var newHTML = "";
  prevIndex = 0;
  arr.forEach(function(item){
    newHTML += content.substring(prevIndex, item[0]);
    newHTML += '<span style="background-color:yellow">' + content.substring(item[0], item[1]) + '</span>';
    prevIndex = item[1];
  });  
  newHTML += content.substring(prevIndex, content.length);
  $("#ptag").html(newHTML);
});
```